# Is it possible to rewrite a url upon landing?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

So for example, if I type in www.website.co.uk/section.php, I want it to automatically load as www.website.co.uk/section. I know how to perform a URL rewrite in that if I type in www.website.co.uk/section, www.website.co.uk/section.php will load but I have so many .php links across my website that I wondered if I can do it the former way somehow to save time?

Comment: Yes, it is known as pretty URLs, search it up. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been searching but wasn't sure what to look for.

Comment: Well you know it is to do with `.htaccess` and you know you want to remove the `.php`, so: *Remove file extension .htaccess php* would make sense.

Comment: Yes I guess it would.